# android - Screens track

Tags: android, android-activity, android-intent

How can know a screen opening from which screen. for example: screen1 and screen2 can go(intent) to screen3. in screen3 how to find user is coming from screen1 or screen2?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `putExtra()` and `getStringExtra()` to solve your problem.
like

In `Screen1 Activity` write this code

```
 Intent intent = new Intent().setClass(Screen1.this, Screen3.class);
         intent.putExtra("caller", "Screen1");
         startActivity(intent);
```

In `Screen2 Activity`, write this code

```
 Intent intent = new Intent().setClass(Screen2.this, Screen3.class);
         intent.putExtra("caller", "Screen2");
         startActivity(intent);
```

And now on `onCreate()` of `Screen3 Activity`

```
String caller = this.getIntent().getStringExtra("caller");
        if(caller != null) {
            if("Screen1".equalsIgnoreCase(caller)) {
                Toast.makeText(this, "Called from screen 1", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            } else if("Screen2".equalsIgnoreCase(caller)){
                Toast.makeText(this, "Called from screen 2", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        }
```

Hope this will clear...

Answer (score 0):

Use this method which return activity class from parrent

```
GetParent()
```

and then something like getId() or getTag() or something on which you can determine if it was screen 1 or screen 2.